# Updating Python on Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

I wanted to update my python 2.6.1 to 3.x on mac but I was wondering if it's possible to do it using the terminal or I have to download the installer from python website?

I am asking this question because the installer is not updating my terminal python version.

Comment: You can install Python3 on Mac by downloading from python.org or use Homebrew. Check out this article for more information.
https://jun711.github.io/devops/how-to-install-python3-on-mac-os/

Answer (score 122, accepted):

The default Python on OS X shouldn't be messed with as it's used by the OS itself. If your default is 2.6.1 then you must have Snow Leopard.

If you just install from the [standard 3.1 disk image](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.1.1/python-3.1.1.dmg) then you can invoke it using `python3.1` from the terminal (you don't have to do any extra steps for this to work) and you can leave the plain `python` as 2.6.1.

Comment: Can i type python3.1 in terminal?

Comment: I didn't know this. If I have already replaced the system's python, what should I do? Should I try to roll back or should I just stay put?

Comment: @AeroWang: If you've replaced it with a 2.x then it's probably safest to leave it alone. If it's a 3.x Python it's more likely to cause issues and I'd switch it back to whichever 2.x is default for your OSX version.

Comment: @ScottGriffiths I did notice a little problem with pip after I did an update but I manually corrected it. Hopefully no more issues. :p

Comment: It seems to be safe to use the pkg-installer (version 3.6.1 for Mac OS X) from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/) from Mac OS X 10.6 onwards.

in order to find out where the python binaries are located use the terminal and type the following commands:

`which python` or `which python3`.

usually this resolves to: 

`/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/local/bin/python3`respectively

Comment: I also have python 2.6 as default, as well as the latest version of python.
My issue is that i want to install scikit-learn and if i try to, by doing "pip install -U scikit-learn" it doesnt detect i have also python3 but automatically directs to the default vers.
Do i need to update default vers of python on terminal?

Comment: @DrFaraday The problem there is that the Python 2 version of pip is being picked up. You can force another version to be used by running it as a module from an explicit python version, for example `python3.6 -m pip install -U scikit-learn`. Or just set up a virtualenv and use that instead.

Answer (score 105):

Both python 2x and 3x can stay installed in a MAC. Mac comes with python 2x version. To check the default python version in your MAC, open the terminal and type-

```
python --version
```

However to check, if you have already installed any of python 3x versions, you need to type

```
python3 --version
```

If you don't then go ahead and install it with the installer. Go the the python's official site(https://www.python.org/downloads/), download the latest version

[image]

and install it.

Now restart the terminal and check again with both commands-

[image]

Comment: You saved me! Thanks.

Answer (score 103):

1. `brew install python` --> install the latest Python.
2. `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*` --> List all Python versions installed on your system.
3. `ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python[your-latest-version-just-installed] /usr/local/bin/python` --> Change default Python version to the latest version.

- **E.g:** `ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /usr/local/bin/python`

4. Restart terminal.
5. `python --version` --> Check Python version default again.

Ref: *https://dev.to/malwarebo/how-to-set-python3-as-a-default-python-version-on-mac-4jjf*

Comment: exec bash -l to restart without closing terminal window.

Comment: Is there a way to upgrade python to 3.9 without brew and without downloading an installer so that I can do it right from my virtual env?

Comment: Command `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*` returns the following error for me:`ls: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory`. I'm on M2 Macbook Air, Ventura

Comment: @Valachio try `ls -l /usr/bin/python*` it worked on my M2 Macbook Air.

Comment: I used `ls -l /opt/homebrew/bin/python*` and it worked on M2 Macbook Pro, Sonoma.

Answer (score 50):

using Homebrew just do:

```
brew install python3 && cp /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

done :)

Comment: What is the purpose of copying the `/usr/local/bin/python3` directory to `/usr/local/bin/python`? Why do that? What is the effect of that?  What $PATH should we be using for this to function correctly in a Homebrew system?  Why am I seeing stuff at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2` and at `/usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: @zipzit It looks like he's doing this so that he can use `python program.py` in the terminal instead of `python3 program.py`. You don't have to copy it over if you don't want to, but you'll need to use `python3` over `python` to run your python 3 programs.

Comment: I hear you, but there are times I've needed python2 to run legacy programs and different times I needed python3.  Here is [the method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284824/remove-and-reinstall-python-on-mac-can-i-trust-these-old-references) I ended up using for my particular issue.

Comment: Copying the binary (rather than symlinking it) is a terrible idea.  The next time you upgrade Python via brew, only /usr/local/bin/python3 will be updated.

Answer (score 46):

This article helped me to make the right choices eventually since mac 10.14.6 by default came with python 2.7* and I had to upgrade to 3.7.*

```
brew install python3
brew update && brew upgrade python
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Referred [The right and wrong way to set Python 3 as default on a Mac](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac) article

Answer (score 16):

Easiest way is

```
 brew update && brew upgrade python
```

Answer (score 14):

Python 2.7 and 3 can co-exist.
Python version shows on terminal is 2.7, but you can invoke it using "python3", see this:

```
PeiwenMAC:git Peiwen$ python --version
Python 2.7.2
PeiwenMAC:git Peiwen$ python3
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 00:54:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: Good answer. But how do I run `pip install -r requirements.txt` with the python3 version on my Mac. I have both python versions as you pointed out.

Comment: @R11G I know this comment is a little bit late but for anyone else having the same issue, you can simply use `python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage your local python versions (both 2.x and 3.x) instead of installing new versions directly with homebrew or building new python versions from source manually. Essentially, `pyenv` can do two key things for you:

- Install different python versions under some directory. Doing `pyenv install 3.8.1` will install python 3.8.1 under `~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1`.
- Modify your shell environment (`PATH`) with shims so that when you do `pyenv local 3.8.1`, calling `python` will invoke the new interpreter instead of your system python.

### MacOSX Specific Installation

The `pyenv` repo is pretty detailed on how to install for different systems and what it's actually doing, but here's the basic steps for mac:

1. Install `homebrew` if you don't already have it and use it to install `pyenv` with `brew install pyenv`
2. Once you have pyenv installed, update your `.bash_profile` file to include:

```
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
    eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

Now install some python using pyenv and then switch to it with the `pyenv local` command (you can see all your versions with `pyenv versions`).

`pyenv install 3.8.1 && pyenv local 3.8.1`

Note: you may need to create a new shell or reload your `bash_profile` in your current shell for the pyenv initialization to do its thing (set up shims).

With this setup, you'll be able to keep your system macosx python and switch to whatever new version of python you want available through `pyenv`.

Comment: do you still need to add this to `.zshrc`? It seems like brew doesn't indicate anything at the end and things seems to work out of the box

Answer (score 5):

I believe Python 3 can coexist with Python 2. Try invoking it using "python3" or "python3.1". If it fails, you might need to uninstall 2.6 before installing 3.1.

Answer (score 3):

I personally wouldn't mess around with OSX's python like they said. My personally preference for stuff like this is just using MacPorts and installing the versions I want via command line. MacPorts puts everything into a separate direction (under /opt I believe), so it doesn't override or directly interfere with the regular system. It has all the usually features of any package management utilities if you are familiar with Linux distros.

I would also suggest installing python_select via MacPorts and using that to select which python you want "active" (it will change the symlinks to point to the version you want). So at any time you can switch back to the Apple maintained version of python that came with OSX or you can switch to any of the ones installed via MacPorts.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, but then after a bit of research I tried

```
brew install python3 && cp /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

in terminal

A warning message will pop-up saying that `python 3.7.0`. is already installed but it's not linked 
so type the command `brew link python` and hit enter and hope things work right for you

Comment: The 3rd answer I've found here suggesting making a copy of the binary rather than symlinking... this is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Its always best to use homebrew to update or install python.
In terminal type:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)
```

This will install homebrew (it takes sometime depending on your internet speed)

Then, in terminal, type

```
brew update
```

This will first update brew (you don't have to do that if you already have the latest version)

then type

```
brew upgrade python
```

This brew will update python to the latest viable version.

That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when you install Python from the install wizard on MAC it will not link to your bash profile. Since you are using homebrew, just to `brew install python` This would install the latest version of Python and then to link them `brew link python@3.9`

Comment: This has been the easiest way for me. Just to do the above and you might need to add `--overwrite` like this `brew link --overwrite python@3.9` to force remove other conflicts. If you want to know what versions you have available then execute this `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
brew upgrade python3
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to achieve the same today. 
The Mac with Snow Leopard comes with Python 2.6.1 version.

Since multiple Python versions can coexist, I downloaded Python 3.2.3 from: http://www.python.org/getit/

After installation the newer Python will be available under the Application folder and the IDE there uses 3.2.3 version of Python.

From the shell, python3  works with the newer version. That serves the purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

Echoing above on not messing with OS X install.  Have been faced with a couple of reinstalls thinking I could beat the system.  The [3.1 install](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.1.1/python-3.1.1.dmg) Scott Griffiths offers above works fine with Yosemite, for any Beta testers out there..  Yosemite has Python 2.7.6 as part of OS install, and typing "python3.1" from terminal launches Python 3.1. Same for Python 3.4 (install [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.1/python-3.4.1-macosx10.6.dmg)).

Answer (score 0):

Instal aws cli via homebrew package manager. It is the simplest and easiest method.

1. If you dont have homebrew installed , enter this command in your terminal

/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

2. Next 'brew install awscli'

This will install aws cli on your mac

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would just leave it as it is.
Use python3 and pip3 to run your files since python and python3 can coexist.

> brew install python3 && cp /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python

You can use the above line but it might have unintended consequences.

Comment: Yes, the unintended consquence is that when you ```brew upgrade python```, /usr/local/bin/python3 will be upgraded, but /usr/local/bin/python will not.  A symlink or alias would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Install Home brew `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

Install python 3 `brew install python3 && cp /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python`

Update python to latest version `ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python[your-latest-version-just-installed] /usr/local/bin/python`

Answer (score 0):

For developers who stay away from Homebrew, you can install it via its installer to any location you want.

https://www.python.org/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to deal with this. This approach allows not just upgrades but downgrades too.

Use `asdf` which allows you to have and switch between multiple versions of the same executable.

```
brew install asdf
asdf plugin add python
asdf install python 3.12.0 (or whichever version you need)
asdf global python 3.12.0
which python
```

I used this to use a specific version of python with my Pycharm.
I recommend checking asdf docs.

Comment: These steps resulted in "python not found" for me.

Comment: You may need to restart your terminal

Answer (score -1):

First, install Homebrew (The missing package manager for macOS) if you haven': Type this in your terminal

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Now you can update your Python to python 3 by this command
`brew install python3 && cp /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python`

Python 2 and python 3 can coexist so to open python 3, type `python3` instead of `python`

That's the easiest and the best way.

Comment: But the next time you upgrade python via brew, /usr/local/bin/python3 will be updated but /usr/local/bin/python will not!   It's far better to ```ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python```

Answer (score -2):

On a mac use the following in the terminal to update python if you have anaconda:

```
conda update python
```

Answer (score -11):

Install JDK latest Version

```sh
export $JAVA_HOME=/usr
export $PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH

java --version

sudo apt install python3.9

python3 --version
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Python3 Installation in MAC steps

Comment: This is not an acceptable solution since it requires updating an unrelated tech stack that some devs are version locked on.