# Installing Python on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

This should be a really simple question, but I'm a little new to all this. I am trying to update my version of Python on Mac OS X 10.6.8. So, I downloaded Python 3.3 from www.python.org, and ran the .dmg file. This then created a "Python 3.3" icon in my Applications folder. However, when I type "python -V" into the Terminal, it prints "Python 2.7.6", so clearly my version of Python has not been updated. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Install `homebrew` then `brew install python`

Comment: You didn't update the version of Python already on your system, you installed an additional version, and now both are available via `python` and `python3` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to actually update the system version of python.

But also, `python3` is the executable name.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.3 is installed in your mac (as you installed it from dmg). it should be invoked in terminal using python3.

[Updating Python on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687357/updating-python-on-mac)

Answer (score 1):

Updating the OS's version of Python could cause potential instability. You should not try to change that. See [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687357/updating-python-on-mac)