# Right path for python on OSX

Tags: python, macos

On my OSX 10.6.8 there was an old version of python installed and it was in:

**System**/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

I downloaded and installed a newer version from the official website and it went to:

/**Library**/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

I was just wondering. Which one is the correct path? And 
Should I move this installation into /System/?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating Python on Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687357/updating-python-on-mac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things that are in System are there for a reason: because they're used by the system. You should not change things in there unless you know what you're doing, and even then not unless you have a very good reason. Library is the right place for software you install for your own use.