# Beginner: errors during installation of Anaconda and update of Python on Bash terminal

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, failed-installation

I am a complete beginner in coding.
So, I'm new to the programming jargons and processes and installations.
Please excuse me if I have misunderstood something.

I have tried to install, uninstall apps completely .. and reinstall.. and update .. Phew! It feels like a mess to me and I'm a little lost without proper direction.
And I feel that the below issues are a part of this installing, and reinstalling.

Current situation:

1. I tried to download Anaconda and at the end of the installation process I got an error message saying installation failed and that I had to contact the manufacturer.
   But, I saw Anaconda navigator in the apps section!

I had tried to remove all the system files before reinstalling Anaconda.

How do I know if its installed properly?

Related to this: can I download/access Atom and PyCharm environments through this Anaconda navigator instead of downloading these two interpreters separately?

2. What does that mean to link Conda interpreter in PyCharm? How is this different?

Because when I used PyCharm previously I had issues assigning an interpreter to the PyCharm projects.

3. I tried to update the Python version on the Mac terminal through the Excode and Homebrew process. And during installation I got a message saying installation had failed.
   But, now when I check on the bash terminal for the Python version it shows Python 3.8.8 !

How is this possible even after the error with the installation?
Now, can I uninstall Excode and Homebrew from my computer?

Comment: Can you please tell me what do you want to do exactly. @Nini

Comment: If you are having problem downloading anaconda you should check https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/troubleshooting/

Comment: To upgrade python on mac try checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687357/updating-python-on-mac

Comment: For linking conda in Pycharm, try checking this video                          https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjqqKrnhYvzAhUVD2MBHayUBSkQwqsBegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D2l1svB8iUYM&usg=AOvVaw0We_DoLXERM9v2OtXSCTjI

Comment: @help I want some guidance and direction in understanding proper installation of these programs without creating more problems for myself. I came across a lot of resources.. but some don't offer specific guidance and that's where I started to feel overwhelmed. I have spent too much time on the set-up part and not enough on the practice.

Comment: Thank you for the links! I will check them out now

Comment: if you are having problem downloading or setup of anything, there are multiple of YouTube video to help , sometime the setup you are installing from a website have a section for beginners.

Comment: Yea, I have been looking at YouTube videos.. I guess I got overwhelmed. Ok, I will check the beginner section.

Comment: Did you find the links found helpful and did the link answer your question, If not please tell. @Nini

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.