# How to update python at /usr/bin/python3 to the latest available via apple xcode command line tools(3.8.9)

Tags: python, macos, security

For cleaning up vulnerabilities in my company, we need to update the system binary install of python located at /usr/bin/python3.

This gets installed and configured when you install XCode Command Line tools, often installed through brew.

The version installed by the tools is 3.8.9. While its outdated, that is fine for now. The real issue is that any devices that are below 3.8.9 need to be updated to 3.8.9.

I was hoping to not uninstall or remove/replace the file located at usr/bin/python3 but I cannot figure out how to update that system binary.

This is for resolving vulnerabilities in our environment, not due to use.

The best answer I have seen is uninstall/reinstall but I'm not sure how that would affect people's local environments.

Comment: If I interpret this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687357/updating-python-on-mac) correctly that python version belongs to the OS and can/should not be changed.

Comment: @Robert sure, and I understand that, but the version that Apple allows for the latest is 3.8.9 and I need to update everyone below up to 3.8.9. Best I’ve found is to rip and replace the command like tools.

Answer (score 0):

The madlads did it! XCode 14 include 8.9.6, so I’m all set